# How to select MS ACCESS OLE Object has data only?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an MS ACCESS 2003 Database the table is like below

```
 id             a                   b                   c

 1           Long binary Data
 2           Long binary Data     Long binary Data
 3           Long binary Data                           Long binary data
 4                                                      Long binary data
 5                                Long binary data
```

I want to select sql query to select column 'b' having long binary data only.

Comment: Did you try `Not Is Null` criteria?

Comment: @June7 what would be the sql query

Comment: Something like: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE NOT b IS NULL;`